# How to capture Karma return/exit code?

Tags: npm, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, bamboo, angular-cli

I am trying to execute some unit test on Bamboo CI. As suggested in Karma config, I do have `SingleRun = true.`
The reporter used is "progress".
Since we build our application using Angular CLI, so I am taking advantage of `ng test --build=false` command which I have set up as a npm script. So, I run my test with command as `npm run <myscriptname>`

problem - I am able to run tests, some pass and some fails, however, my task always returns success as long as I am able to run tests.

I am trying to avoid using gulp/grunt, so if possible let me know something without it. I have also tried directly calling `Karma start <config file>` but that too didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a **Script task** instead of the **Command**. In the script body you can run your script in the same way and try to capture the exit command with "$?", and manually send the exit code. Also make sure your script returns non-zero code if tests failed.

```
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
    echo "The script returned non-zero error code!" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. However, I doubt if this will work. The reason, Since I was using ng test to run karma test, it was consuming exit status returned by karma and so as long as I am able to run test, it says its good irrespective of any test failures. (yes, I have find solution too. Now I am running Karma directly)

Comment: This solution worked for me, thanks so much! I was stuck with it for so many hours. @TypeScripter, you can catch the exit code even with using ng test, at least it worked in my case. In Jenkins I call a shell script, which enters into the angular project folder, run this: ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless  --single-run    and after that, insert the code snippet above with exit 1. Works like a charm!

Comment: This solution worked for me as well. Thanks. You can even run any custom script from the package.json e.g   </localdisk/opt/nodejs/current/bin/>npm run code-coverage.

Answer (score 4):

Now able to find correct status by Karma. 
Issue - When we were executing Karma via ng test. all exit statuses returned by karma were being consumed by ng. So, we used to get "Success" as long as we are able to run tests (irrespective of test failures)

Solution - Call karma directly. This way we can handle exit status which helps during CI.

Comment: We had a similar issue, but the other way around. Our test suite was passing, we got a SUCCESS message, but the exit status from `ng` was always 1, no matter what.